# Deleting LinkedList With Specific Value Only Once

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm writing a program and in one of the functions I have to remove a value from a LinkedList

```
struct node *delete_val(int value, struct node *head) {

struct node *h1 = head;
if (head == NULL) { return NULL;}
if (head->next == NULL) { free(head); return NULL;}
while (h1 != NULL) {
    if (h1->next != NULL && h1->next->data == value){
        h1->next = h1->next->next;
        } else {
    h1 = h1->next;
}
free(h1);
return head;
}
}
```

If passed:

> (4,[3,4,5,6,4,4,7]);

The function should return:

> [3,5,6,4,4,7]

But my function is getting the error:

> Error: the list returned by your function is invalid.
>          The next field of node 0 is invalid (0xf5400650).

I'm basically checking to see if the next node contains the matching value in its 'data' (head->next->data), and if it does, I'll re-switch the pointer of the current linkedlist (head->next) to the one after it (head->next->next) but I can't even get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is are two problem.

1. You need to break after correcting links (because you want to delete value once)
2. You are freeing incorrect member.

if you correct these two, I think it should be ok.

```
struct node *delete_val(int value, struct node *head) {
    struct node *h1 = head;
    struct node *tmp =  NULL;

    if (head == NULL) { return NULL;}
    if (head->next == NULL) { free(head); return NULL;}

    while (h1 != NULL) {
        if (h1->next != NULL && h1->next->data == value){
            tmp = h1->next;
            h1->next = h1->next->next;
            break;            
        } else {
            h1 = h1->next;
        }    
    }

    free(tmp);
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After making sure that the linked list is not already empty, instead of

```
if (head->next == NULL) { free(head); return NULL;}
```

do

```
if(head->next == NULL)
{
    if(head->data == value)
    {
        free(head);
        return NULL;
    }
    return head;
}
```

You free the first node only if its `data` is the value to be deleted.

By this point, we are sure that there are at least 2 nodes in the linked list.

```
struct node *temp=NULL, *ptr=head;
while(ptr->next!=NULL)
{
    if(ptr->next->data==value)
    {
        printf("\nElement to be deleted found.");
        temp=ptr->next;
        ptr->next=ptr->next->next;
        free(temp);
        break;
    }
    ptr=ptr->next;
}
printf("\nElement to be deleted not found in the list.");
return head;
```

We look ahead to see if the next node's `data` is `value`. If so, the `next` of the node before the node to be deleted is made equal to the `next` of the node being deleted and then the memory for the node to be deleted is deallocated with `free()`.